# ModalViewController with embedded nav controller - Unable to dismiss

Tags: objective-c, ios, modalviewcontroller

I present a modalViewController that is actually a navigation controller with one view, and a custom navigation bar. The modal view appears fine as expected, but when I attempt to remove it from view using [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES], I am hitting a "-[UINavigationController modalViewController]: message sent to deallocated instance". Can't seem to figure this out. Any ideas?

Instantiating the ModalViewController:

```
    // Make a navigation controller and add the view inside it
    MyViewController *evc=[[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];
    //UINavigationController *nvc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:evc];
    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"UINavigationBarWithBackgroundImage" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *nvc = [[nib instantiateWithOwner:nil options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    [nvc setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:evc]];
    evc.delegate=self;
    [evc release];
    [self presentModalViewController:nvc animated:YES];
    [nvc release];
```

and trying to remove it. This is where the error comes in:

```
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about this, but try it anyway:

Remove

```
[nvc release]
```

and see if

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

now works.

Comment: This solved it.... very weird! I thought that the nvc would be owned by the parent view, since it was it's modalview. Very strange behavior, but this fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you are loading two seperate nibs to show this modal? You do not need to load a nib containing a navigation controller to get this working.

Try something like this:

```
// Make a navigation controller and add the view inside it
MyViewController *evc= [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];

UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:evc];

evc.delegate=self;

[self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];

[evc release];
[navController release];
```

Comment: I'm loading two nibs as the navigation controller comes from a class with a custom navigation bar image. This seemed to be easiest way to override the nav bar image

Comment: Just as a side note, if your app is targeted to iOS 5 only there is a much better way to set a custom navbar image. Take a look here [UINavigationBar Apple Developer Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationBar_Class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006887-CH3-SW16)